# c++ stl convolution

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, convolution

Is there a nice implementation of the algorithm to calculate the **convolution** of two ranges in C++ STL (or even boost)?
i.e. something with prototype (convolution of two ranges `a..b` and `c..d`):

```
template< class Iterator >
void convolution(Iterator a, Iterator b, Iterator c, Iterator d);
```

which modifies `a..b` range

Comment: It's not hard to write one that adds to a third range initially filled with zeros.  In-place, I don't know.

Comment: Assuming this is going to be a discrete convolution where the ranges are the same length writing this isn't too hard - it'd be fairly similar to transform. In fact, you may even be able to use transform to do this with the 3rd parameter being a reverse iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes std::transform

```
std::transform(a, b, c, a, Op);

// a b is the the first input range
// c   is the start of the second range (which must be at least as large as (b-a)
// 
// We then use a as the output iterator as well.

// Op is a BinaryFunction
```

To answer the comment on how to perform accumulation of state in the comments:

```
struct Operator
{
    State& state;
    Operator(Sate& state) : state(state) {}
    Type operator()(TypeR1 const& r1Value, TypeR2 const& r2Value) const
    {
        Plop(state, r1Value, r2Value);
        return Convolute(state, r2Value, r2Value);
    }
};
State  theState  = 0;
Operator Op(theState);
```

Comment: It seems to me that each of the STL algorithms consists of a single loop of some kind. Therefore, most likely, not just one STL algorithm express the solution of the problem but the combination (i.e. `std::inner_product` and `std::transform`) can.

Comment: I don't see how `Op` could accumulate all O(n^2) product terms without internally building a large temporary container.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: That's easy make Op a functor.

Comment: @LokiAstari: But do you agree that the `State` member in your example will need to contain two temporary containers -- one to hold all the elements in the first sequence that have been seen so far, and another for all the the elements of the second sequence that have been seen so far?  `Plop()` needs to add each of the 2 new elements passed into `operator()()` to these internal containers, and `Convolute()` will need to loop over (this could be done using `std::inner_product()`) building up a sum of products.  Finally, one of the iterator ranges needs to be reversed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what a "convolution" from two sequences to one of these two sequences is supposed to be: It seems to be a different understanding than my understanding. Below is a version of [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_%28computer_science%29) using a variable number of iterators. Because I'm actually just too lazy for now, I'll use a somewhat uncommon notion of passing the destination iterator as first argument rather than as last argument. Here is an implementation of a corresponding `zip()` algorithms:

```
#include <tuple>

namespace algo
{
    template <typename... T>
    void dummy(T...)
    {
    }

    template <typename To, typename InIt, typename... It>
    To zip(To to, InIt it, InIt end, It... its)
    {
        for (; it != end; ++it, ++to) {
            *to = std::make_tuple(*it, *its...);
            algo::dummy(++its...);
        }
        return to;
    }
}
```

Below is a simple test program I used to verify that the above does what I intended it to do:

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

enum class e { a = 'a', b = 'b', c = 'c' };

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out,
                          std::tuple<int, double, e> const& v)
{
    return out << "["
               << std::get<0>(v) << ", "
               << std::get<1>(v) << ", "
               << char(std::get<2>(v)) << "]";
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::tuple<int, double, e> tuple;
    std::vector<int>   v{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::deque<double> d{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 };
    std::list<e>       l{ e::a, e::b, e::c };
    std::vector<tuple> r;

    algo::zip(std::back_inserter(r), v.begin(), v.end(), d.begin(), l.begin());

    std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<tuple>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: With a bit more template code, you can get it to also ensure that the lengths of the variadically passed iterators match, provided you call zip(OutIt, InIt, InItPack...) and InItPack contains argument pairs (*not* std::pair<InIt>). However, it's about 150 lines of code, mainly due to gratuitous use of recursive templates for helper functions.